# Cannot see the option to install Ubuntu 15.10 alongside Windows 10

Tags: boot, system-installation, 15.10

I couldn't find any proper answer to this but I can't seem to get install Ubuntu 15.10 alongside Windows 10 because the installer does not show that option. My Windows 10 is installed in Legacy Mode so I'm not really sure what to do here. EDIT: Disabled Fast boot and hibernate. Seriously need help

Comment: Not only wubi is no longer maintained or recommended, Ubuntu 14.10 is no longer supported.

Comment: Hi zadic we recommend first using Ubuntu 15.10 so you have the latest which has already been tested alongside Windows 10 a lot. Enjoy friend.

Comment: Well Im not getting that option either in Ubuntu 15.10 installer.

Comment: @xangua: Apparently Wubi is now working again and maintained by the community.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

Answer (score 0):

I have laptop with `UEFI` technology, and for installing dual boot is pain.
Try to identify your laptop first, and if it have `UEFI`, you can learn a little about `UEFI` [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/175649/what-you-need-to-know-about-using-uefi-instead-of-the-bios/).